# Having divs act as button objects to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I populated a list using the following code. 
I'm trying to make each of the objects retrieved from the server act like a button and when clicked throw a pop up box displaying address, date, and status. Is there anyway to do this? I've been looking into using Ajax but it is getting a little confusing as I have an html file and a php file that has all my javascript/php (the javascript relies on a php function) and from what I've read I would need to make another php file to service the request. How then would I reference it within my html file to do so? I may be making this harder than it needs to be.

Original Code:

```
<?php
    function getjson(){
        $db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect to Mysql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $sql = "SELECT misc, lng, lat FROM information WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['user_name'] . "';";
        $result = $db_connection->query($sql);
        $temp = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $temp[] = $row;
        }

        $db_connection->close();
        $json = json_encode($temp);         
        return $json;   
    }

    function getwarnings(){
        $username = $_SESSION['user_name'];
        $db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect to Mysql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $sql = "SELECT misc, date, id, address, status FROM information WHERE username = '" . $username . "';";
        $result = $db_connection->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                switch($row["status"]){
                    case 3:
                        echo '<div id= "content" style = "background-color: red" onclick = popinformation(' . $row["id"] . ')> ' . $row["address"] . "</div>";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        echo '<div id= "content" style = "background-color: yellow" onclick = popinformation(' . $row["id"] . ')> ' . $row["address"] . "</div>";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        echo '<div id= "content" style = "background-color: green" onclick = popinformation(' . $row["id"] . ')> ' . $row["address"] . "</div>";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        $db_connection->close(); 
    }

    function getalerts($id){
        $db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect to Mysql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        $sql = "SELECT misc, date, id, address, status FROM information WHERE id = '" . $id . "';";
        $result = $db_connection->query($sql);
        $temp = array();
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $temp[] = $row;

        $db_connection->close();

        return json_encode($temp);
    }
?>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

function getlocations(){
    var data = <?php echo getjson(); ?>;
    var i = 0;
    var locations = new Array();
    for(i; i < data.length; i++){
        var dataholder = [data[i].misc, parseFloat(data[i].lat), parseFloat(data[i].lng)];
        locations.push(dataholder);
    }
    return locations;
}

function createmap(){
    var locations = getlocations();

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 13,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.624561, -122.356445),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
}

    function popinformation(data){
    var json = <?php getalerts(); ?>
    console.log(json);
}
```

Update:

Here's what I was trying, from what I've read I have a misunderstanding of php/javascript. This is all my code within the file. Colors appear fine but pop-ups do not appear, Console reports Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < which will go away if I delete the final script. I think that means the error is within the echo json_encode($results) somehow.

```
<?php
function getjson(){
    $db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to Mysql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT misc, lng, lat FROM information WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['user_name'] . "';";
    $result = $db_connection->query($sql);
    $temp = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $temp[] = $row;
    }

    $db_connection->close();
    $json = json_encode($temp);         
    return $json;   
}

function getwarnings(){
    $username = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to Mysql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT misc, date, id, address, status FROM information WHERE username = '" . $username . "';";
    $result = $db_connection->query($sql);

    $colors = array(3 => 'red', 4 => 'yellow', 5 => 'green');
    $results = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $results[$row['id']] = $row;
        echo '<div class="content" style = "background-color: ' . $colors[$row['status']] . '" data-id="' . $row["id"] . '"> ' . $row["address"] . "</div>";
    }

    $db_connection->close(); 
}

function getalerts($id){
    $db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to Mysql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $sql = "SELECT date, id, address, status FROM information WHERE id = '" . $id . "';";
    $result = $db_connection->query($sql);
    $temp = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $temp[] = $row;
    }

    $db_connection->close();
    $json = json_encode($temp);         
    return $json; 
}
    ?>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"   type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

function getlocations(){
    var data = <?php echo getjson(); ?>;
    var i = 0;
    var locations = new Array();
    for(i; i < data.length; i++){
        var dataholder = [data[i].misc, parseFloat(data[i].lat), parseFloat(data[i].lng)];
        locations.push(dataholder);
    }
    return locations;
}

function createmap(){
    var locations = getlocations();

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 13,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.624561, -122.356445),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
}
    </script>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var information_object = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
    $(".content").click(function() {
        var info = information_object[$(this).data('id')];
        if (info) {
            alert("Address: " + info.address + "\nDate: " + info.date + "\nStatus: " + info.status);
        } else {
            alert("Invalid ID: " + id);
        }
    });
});
```

My html Document

```
    <html>
    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/logged_in.css">
       <?php    
           include("login_php_scripts.php");
       ?>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="navigation">
       <a href="index.php?logout">Account</a> 
       <a href="index.php?logout">Logout</a>
    </div>

   <div id="header">
      <div id="logo"></div>
      <div id="header_text"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="content_wrapper">
     <div id="list_view">
          I am logged in as: <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?></br>
          <?php 
             getwarnings();
           ?>


     </div>

  <div id="map">
      <script> 
        createmap();
      </script>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to provide your `javascript` that is where creating the popup is going to come into play

Comment: You can't use the same `id="content"` in every DIV, IDs should be unique.

Comment: Yeah I know, I meant to change them to classes but forgot to go back and do so. Thanks for pointing that out!
Trying something but I don't want to seem like an idiot.... which will probably happen anyways. I'll post my javascript/updated php in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the database results into an array, then convert that to a Javascript object that your popup function can look up by ID.

```
function getwarnings(){
    $username = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to Mysql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT misc, date, id, address, status FROM information WHERE username = '" . $username . "';";
    $result = $db_connection->query($sql);

    $colors = array(3 => 'red', 4 => 'yellow', 5 => 'green');
    $results = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $results[$row['id']] = $row;
        echo '<div class="content" style = "background-color: ' . $colors[$row['status']] . '" data-id="' . $row["id"] . '"> ' . $row["address"] . "</div>";
    }
    $db_connection->close(); 
    ?>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var information_object = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
        $(".content").click(function() {
            var info = information_object[$(this).data('id')];
            if (info) {
                alert("Address: " + info.address + "\nDate: " + info.date + "\nStatus: " + info.status);
            } else {
                alert("Invalid ID: " + id);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I believe this almost works, it displays the color, map, format of the webpage correctly but when I click on a div nothing pops up. 
The console reports Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Which is extremely difficult to find. Error goes away when I delete the script so I believe it has something to do with the php inside the script.

Comment: Had some quoting errors in the echo line, try it now.

Comment: Yeap fixed those, still reports the same error to the console. Been trying to study the error on other posts but it's a pretty vague error. From what I've read it has something to do with how the response is being handled from the server. Sorry for all the questions, kinda new to this type of programming.

Comment: It's probably another quoting problem. The `<` that's part of an HTML tag is being seen as part of the Javascript.

Comment: Looking within the chrome debugger I can see 
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var information_object = <br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice'

followed by a bunch of nasty formatting code.

Comment: You're running your script with XDebug enabled. When it reports errors, it assumes the output is HTML, so it puts HTML markup around it.

Comment: Try to find the error message inside the formatting code, and fix the problem.

Comment: Ahh, the problem is that you have `echo json_encode($results)` outside the `getwarnings` function, so the `$results` variable is not in scope.

Comment: What happened to the original code in your question? My answer doesn't make sense when you change the question to use my code.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show where the script should be.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had an error I couldn't figure out and after studying many jquery tutorials, reading many other boards I realized I forgot...... the  header. 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">

Anyone else using this make sure to include this.